# Oracle - SQL, pulling time rages from within a date range

Tags: sql, oracle, date, time

I'm trying to write a select statement to return average values over a specific time range over a specific date range. For example I'd like to know the avg(max_percent_util) over the past 7 days during the time frames 4pm-11pm, all day, and 8am-6pm. This is what I have so far and I'm not sure the query will ever end at this point.

```
select 
sdpt.DOWN_DESC, 
avg(sdpt.max_percent_util) seven_day_prime,
avg(sday.max_percent_util) seven_day,
avg(sdb.max_percent_util) seven_day_business

from 

(select down_desc, hour_stamp, max_percent_util from downstream_hour_facts 
where ((hour_stamp >= sysdate-8 AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') >= '16:00' AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') <= '23:00')
or (hour_stamp >= sysdate-7 AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') >= '16:00' AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') <= '23:00')
or (hour_stamp >= sysdate-6 AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') >= '16:00' AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') <= '23:00')
or (hour_stamp >= sysdate-5 AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') >= '16:00' AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') <= '23:00')
or (hour_stamp >= sysdate-4 AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') >= '16:00' AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') <= '23:00')
or (hour_stamp >= sysdate-3 AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') >= '16:00' AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') <= '23:00')
or (hour_stamp >= sysdate-2 AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') >= '16:00' AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') <= '23:00')
or (hour_stamp >= sysdate-1 AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') >= '16:00' AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') <= '23:00'))) sdpt,

(select down_desc, hour_stamp, max_percent_util from downstream_hour_facts 
where ((hour_stamp >= sysdate-8) or (hour_stamp >= sysdate-7) or (hour_stamp >= sysdate-6)
or (hour_stamp >= sysdate-5) or (hour_stamp >= sysdate-4) or (hour_stamp >= sysdate-3)
or (hour_stamp >= sysdate-2) or (hour_stamp >= sysdate-1))) sday,

(select down_desc, hour_stamp, max_percent_util from downstream_hour_facts 
where ((hour_stamp >= sysdate-8 AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') >= '8:00' AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') <= '18:00')
or (hour_stamp >= sysdate-7 AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') >= '08:00' AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') <= '18:00')
or (hour_stamp >= sysdate-6 AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') >= '08:00' AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') <= '18:00')
or (hour_stamp >= sysdate-5 AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') >= '08:00' AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') <= '18:00')
or (hour_stamp >= sysdate-4 AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') >= '08:00' AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') <= '18:00')
or (hour_stamp >= sysdate-3 AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') >= '08:00' AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') <= '18:00')
or (hour_stamp >= sysdate-2 AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') >= '08:00' AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') <= '18:00')
or (hour_stamp >= sysdate-1 AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') >= '08:00' AND to_char(hour_stamp, 'HH24:MI') <= '18:00'))) sdb
where sdpt.down_desc = sday.down_desc and sday.down_desc = sdb.down_desc
group by sdpt.DOWN_DESC
order by sdpt.down_desc
```

Example output that i'm looking to re-create:

- Metric:                       Utilization Data
- Previous 24 Hours:            7.15%
- 7 Day Rolling (all hours):        7.12%
- 7 Day Rolling Prime Time (4-12):  7.12%
- 7 Day Rolling Business Hours (9-5):   7.12%

Comment: This look hidious, which version are you using?, you do know that Oracle has date and time functions? see: http://psoug.org/reference/date_func.html

Comment: Version of sql developer is "Version 3.0.04" I'm not a DBA by any means so i couldn't tell you what version the server is.... Sorry if the query looks/is "hideous" but i had no other avenues to try. I am aware that oracle has date and time functions but i don't know how to utilize them correctly to perform this task

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One reason that your query isso slow is that you're not camparing dates, you're comparing strings; using TO_CHAR().  You're also doing a lot of redundant work.

Here is an example that parses the data once (not three times), avoids string comparisons, and so should quickly filter the data down to the 8 and a bit days you want.

```
WITH
  filtered_data AS
(
  SELECT
    down_desc,
    hour_stamp,
    TRUNC(hour_stamp)                date_stamp,
    hour_stamp - TRUNC(hour_stamp)   time_stamp
  FROM
    downstream_hour_facts
  WHERE
    hour_stamp >= TRUNC(sysdate) - 8
)
SELECT
  down_desc,
  AVG(CASE WHEN date_stamp >= TRUNC(sysdate)
           THEN max_percent ELSE NULL END)          today,
  AVG(CASE WHEN date_stamp <  TRUNC(sysdate)
           THEN max_percent ELSE NULL END)          seven_day_all,
  AVG(CASE WHEN date_stamp <  TRUNC(sysdate)
            AND time_stamp >= TO_TIMESTAMP('16:00', 'HH24:MI')
            AND time_stamp <  TO_TIMESTAMP('23:00', 'HH24:MI')
           THEN max_percent ELSE NULL END)          seven_day_prime,
  AVG(CASE WHEN date_stamp <  TRUNC(sysdate)
            AND time_stamp >= TO_TIMESTAMP('08:00', 'HH24:MI')
            AND time_stamp <  TO_TIMESTAMP('16:00', 'HH24:MI')
           THEN max_percent ELSE NULL END)          seven_day_business
FROM
  filtered_data
GROUP BY
  down_desc
ORDER BY
  down_desc
```

**EDIT**

I've also noticed that you're joinging the data in a 'dangerously' incorrect way...

Sub Query 1 may return 9 records for a metric.
Sub Query 2 may return 3 records for that metric.
Sub Query 3 may return 4 records for that metric.

But then you join them *only* by the metric.  All 9 records from SQ1 match all 3 from SQ2 (27 records now), and all of them match all 4 from SQ3 (108 records now).

When joining sets of data be very careful that each record joins to where it's needed, and only where it's needed.

*(The single parse version above should totally avoid that problem anyway.)*

Comment: Do those hourly comparisons (`time_stamp > '04:00'`) work?  When I `SELECT 'x' FROM DUAL WHERE (SYSDATE - TRUNC(SYSDATE)) > '04:00'`, I get "ORA-01722: invalid number."  Am I missing something?

Comment: I tried this and i get and error.
    ORA-01722: invalid number
    01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
    *Cause:    
    *Action:

Additionally, the tables should always have a result, there are no time frames that are missing the data that i'm requesting. So joining on the only variable that's unique (down_desc) seemed like the only proper way to combine. (the query finished after an hour)

Comment: i think i figured out my issue. the time_stamp generated in the filtered_data was returning a decimal (ex. 0.0416666 for 01:00) instead of a time formatted number.. don't ask, but i found if you multiply by 60 (for seconds in a minute??) then divide by 24 (hours in a day??) then multiply by 10 (no clue) you get a number that's closer to the hour (01:00 = 1, 02:00 = 2...etc) changed the times down below to use just the hour:
    `AVG(CASE WHEN date_stamp <  TRUNC(sysdate)
    AND time_stamp >= '16'
    AND time_stamp <  '23'
    THEN max_percent ELSE NULL END) seven_day_prime,`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, to much haste and confusion over what works on which RDBSM :)  Editted to wrap the times in TO_TIMESTAMP().  Give that a try?  (Your number based idea should work [0.041666 of a day = 1 hour], but don't put quotes around them, they're not strings, they're numbers...)